# Laravell PHPUnit database test consume 16Gb ram and crashes

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

I tried to make a unit test that makes a database query, but any time I run `php artisan test`, PHP starts consuming memory until there is no free RAM on my virtual server.

For testing I have increase the virtual server RAM up to 16 Gb and it consumes all 16 GB and then crashes!

So I got simple test from a Laravel tutorial project and tried creating a unit test on it.

Here is the Model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Traits\Timestamp;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Student extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, HasApiTokens;

    protected $table = "students";

    protected $fillable = [
        "name",
        "email",
        "password",
        "phone_no",
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

And a Unit Test:

```php
namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Models\Student;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setup() : void
    {
        $this->setup();
    }

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_example()
    {
        $st = new Student();

        $st->select("*")->get();
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And the testing result:

```php
   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessSignaledException 

  The process has been signaled with signal "9".

  at vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:441
    437▕             usleep(1000);
    438▕         }
    439▕ 
    440▕         if ($this->processInformation['signaled'] && $this->processInformation['termsig'] !== $this->latestSignal) {
  ➜ 441▕             throw new ProcessSignaledException($this);
    442▕         }
    443▕ 
    444▕         return $this->exitcode;
    445▕     }

      +15 vendor frames 
  16  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I tried many thing, change settings and etc, but nothing helped!

**Update 1**

Just for information:

```
php -v
PHP 8.1.10 (cli) (built: Sep 18 2022 12:52:19) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

**Update 2**
I create simple minimal project:

https://github.com/vasiliyaltunin/LaravelPhpUnitDatabase

So you can test it yourself, maybe there PHP version problem or other things i try everything already!

**Update 3**

Thansk to all problem resolved!

I hope test project help ppls to understand how database testing works.

I updated test project by adding seeder for table and use RefreshDatabase, so on every tests run it will be wipe and reseed tables!

You can remove use RefreshDatabase; if you dont want to loose you data every time!

Comment: Try changing `use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;` to `use Tests\TestCase` assuming you are using the Laravel boilerplate app

Comment: because you are querying the whole database, try to limit to `1` for example

Comment: You can use `$st = Student::all();` instead. Creating new object from `Student` class doesn't make any sense in this situation.

Comment: Using $st = Student::all(); did not help Using use Tests\TestCase; not help

Comment: Also table currently have no records and i try to: use RefreshDatabase; in class and this did not help

Comment: I create demo project so you can test it yourself, see Update 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup method is creating an infinite loop:

```
    public function setup() : void
    {
        $this->setup(); // calling itself infinite times
    }
```

Probably you want to call `parent::setup()` instead:

```
    public function setup() : void
    {
        parent::setup();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I think i just messed with this at some point. It helps! Anyway i update test project and it works just fine!